# What does "cycling through" mean when talk about compare and choose from a set of candidates?

Tags: word-usage

In the middle of a PCA algorithm course, the lecturer is comparing a set of candidates.

It sounds like the lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/q0s52ul-Lns?t=347)

> ... here I'm plotting the original data set with their corresponding
>   projections on two one-dimensional subspaces and I'm cycling through a
>   couple of options of subspaces ...

What does "cycling through" mean in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "cycle through" a set of options means to try each one in turn with to see which is best. He will repeat the projection of the data set into the each of the sub-spaces in-turn. In this video he tried several line slopes to fit a line to his x,y 
data through (0,0), he **cycled through** the slopes { 0, 1/2, 1, 2, infinity, -2, -1, -1/2 } and looked at the size of the average squared reconstruction error J, which he wants to minimize.

Comment: so, He projected the same dataset X onto a couple of subspaces, namely, a number of lines with slopes {0, 1/2, 1, 2, infinity, -2, -1, -1/2},  and compared the corresponding J to choose a minimal one, is my understanding right?

Comment: That's what I got out of the video, this was a brute-force numerical method to gain intuition about what he's going to use partial derivatives to find analytically in the next video.